# Chromium embedded minimal client WM_paint stops working after minimizing and restoring

Tags: delphi, chromium-embedded

Apparently, the basic delphi chromium embedded minimal or cefclient demo is unable to focus back the window while it is minimized and then restored. I am unable to click on anything, however, if you resize the window, it's going back to normal, being able to click and use the browser as usual.

Later edit : I'm using DCEF3 , latest version from https://github.com/svn2github/dcef3 , CEF3 3.1364.1094 to be more specific.

Does anybody have any idea how to repaint that browser after minimizing and restoring in Delphi XE3 ?

Actual code:

```
program cefclient;

uses
  Windows, Messages, ceflib;

type
  TCustomClient = class(TCefClientOwn)
  private
    FLifeSpan: ICefLifeSpanHandler;
  protected
    function GetLifeSpanHandler: ICefLifeSpanHandler; override;
  public
    constructor Create; override;
  end;

  TCustomLifeSpan = class(TCefLifeSpanHandlerOwn)
  protected
    procedure OnAfterCreated(const browser: ICefBrowser); override;
    procedure OnBeforeClose(const browser: ICefBrowser); override;
  end;

type
  TWindowProc = Pointer;
  WNDPROC = Pointer;

var
  Window: HWND;
  handl: ICefClient = nil;
  brows: ICefBrowser = nil;
  browserId: Integer = 0;
  navigateto: ustring = 'http://google.com';

function CefWndProc(Wnd: HWND; message: UINT; wParam: Integer; lParam: Integer): Integer; stdcall;
var
  ps: PAINTSTRUCT;
  info: TCefWindowInfo;
  rect: TRect;
  hdwp: THandle;
  setting: TCefBrowserSettings;
begin
  case message of
    WM_PAINT:
      begin
        BeginPaint(Wnd, ps);
        EndPaint(Wnd, ps);
        result := 0;
      end;
    WM_CREATE:
      begin
        handl := TCustomClient.Create;
        GetClientRect(Wnd, rect);
        FillChar(info, SizeOf(info), 0);
        info.Style := WS_CHILD or WS_VISIBLE or WS_CLIPCHILDREN or WS_CLIPSIBLINGS or WS_TABSTOP;
        info.parent_window := Wnd;
        info.x := rect.left;
        info.y := rect.top;
        info.Width := rect.right - rect.left;
        info.Height := rect.bottom - rect.top;
        FillChar(setting, sizeof(setting), 0);
        setting.size := SizeOf(setting);
        CefBrowserHostCreateSync(@info, handl, navigateto, @setting);
        SetTimer(Wnd, 1, 100, nil);
        result := 0;
      end;
    WM_DESTROY:
      begin
        brows := nil;
        PostQuitMessage(0);
        result := DefWindowProc(Wnd, message, wParam, lParam);
      end;
    WM_SETFOCUS:
      begin
        if brows <> nil then
          PostMessage(brows.Host.WindowHandle, WM_SETFOCUS, wParam, 0);
        Result := 0;
      end;
    WM_SIZE:
      begin
        if(brows <> nil) then
        begin
          // Resize the browser window and address bar to match the new frame
          // window size
          GetClientRect(Wnd, rect);
          hdwp := BeginDeferWindowPos(1);
          hdwp := DeferWindowPos(hdwp, brows.Host.WindowHandle, 0, rect.left, rect.top,
            rect.right - rect.left, rect.bottom - rect.top, SWP_NOZORDER);
          EndDeferWindowPos(hdwp);
        end;
        result := DefWindowProc(Wnd, message, wParam, lParam);
      end;
    WM_CLOSE:
      begin
        if brows <> nil then
          brows.Host.ParentWindowWillClose;
        result := DefWindowProc(Wnd, message, wParam, lParam);
      end
  else
    result := DefWindowProc(Wnd, message, wParam, lParam);
  end;
end;

{ TCustomClient }

constructor TCustomClient.Create;
begin
  inherited;
  FLifeSpan := TCustomLifeSpan.Create;
end;

function TCustomClient.GetLifeSpanHandler: ICefLifeSpanHandler;
begin
  Result := FLifeSpan;
end;

{ TCustomLifeSpan }

procedure TCustomLifeSpan.OnAfterCreated(const browser: ICefBrowser);
begin
  if not browser.IsPopup then
  begin
    // get the first browser
    brows := browser;
    browserId := brows.Identifier;
  end;
end;

procedure TCustomLifeSpan.OnBeforeClose(const browser: ICefBrowser);
begin
  if browser.Identifier = browserId then
    brows := nil;
end;

var
  wndClass : TWndClass;
begin
  // multi process
  CefSingleProcess := False;
  if not CefLoadLibDefault then Exit;
  try
    wndClass.style         := CS_HREDRAW or CS_VREDRAW;
    wndClass.lpfnWndProc   := @CefWndProc;
    wndClass.cbClsExtra    := 0;
    wndClass.cbWndExtra    := 0;
    wndClass.hInstance     := hInstance;
    wndClass.hIcon         := LoadIcon(0, IDI_APPLICATION);
    wndClass.hCursor       := LoadCursor(0, IDC_ARROW);
    wndClass.hbrBackground := 0;
    wndClass.lpszMenuName  := nil;
    wndClass.lpszClassName := 'cefapp';

    RegisterClass(wndClass);

    Window := CreateWindow(
      'cefapp',
      'Chromium',
      WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW or WS_CLIPCHILDREN,
      Integer(CW_USEDEFAULT),
      Integer(CW_USEDEFAULT),
      Integer(CW_USEDEFAULT),
      Integer(CW_USEDEFAULT),
      0,
      0,
      HInstance,
      nil);

    ShowWindow(Window, SW_SHOW);
    UpdateWindow(Window);
    CefRunMessageLoop;
  finally
    handl := nil;
  end;
end.
```

Comment: Which version of DCEF ? DCEF1 or DCEF3 ? And which version exactly ? Could you include this information into your question, please ?

Comment: @TLama updated my question with that data, thanks in advance.

Comment: What does that paint handler supposed to do? Currently it does nothing other than generating an WM_ERASEBKGND. Try removing it altogether, so that the default window procedure is called. Focus handler is also curious, I'd try removing that too.

Comment: FWIW, I tried and couldn't duplicate the problems stated here using a more [recent version](https://code.google.com/p/dcef3/source/browse/#git%2Fsrc) (which use libcef 3.1547.1412) than the latest in the clone.

Comment: @Sertac, and were you able to reproduce it with v.3.1364.1094 ? I was in Delphi XE3.

Comment: @TLama - I have XE2, and only tested as I commented. But there are some updates to the code (not just libcef but dcef also), why test with an outdated version?

Comment: @Sertac, then I must have something wrong with my repository, because my [`TortoiseGit`](https://code.google.com/p/tortoisegit/) shown no changes since [`this commit`](https://code.google.com/p/dcef3/source/detail?r=2fe0a7f36e986370e5ab95cc9edfd88096062eee), so I assumed that DCEF3 with CEF v3.1364.1094 is the latest available. Well, then if you say so, it could be enough to just upgrade.

Comment: @TLama - The link in your comment is more recent than the one in the question (which is an older clone), and also it shouldn't have the libcef version you quote (it should be 3.1453.1255). See [here](https://code.google.com/p/dcef3/source/list). In any case the issue might have something to do with the environment the code is run, which I can't tell..

Comment: @TLama - Your git client is playing various tricks on you. I downloaded libcef.dll from your link, which is indeed 3.1453.1255.0. Additionally it doesn't show three commits since 11 oct 2013.

Comment: Can someone send me a link with the latest updates from the repo ? I'm on another PC and I'd like testing it here too but I don't have rights to install SVN here (not my PC). Thanks

Comment: @edduvs - I've posted the link several times now. Anyway, for your convenience, visit [here](https://code.google.com/p/dcef3/source/browse/) and click the 'download zip' link.

Comment: @SertacAkyuz ah sorry, I've looked so much around for a download link on google code it , weeks ago, couldn't find anything but connecting with a SVN app, I'll try it and get back with some info.

Comment: @edduvs - No problem. I hope your problem goes away with that version.